# form submit and return value (remote: true) - rails way?

Tags: javascript, ruby, ajax

I am trying to make a form using remote: true
So fas it's working well, but I can't get the result back
Is their a rails's way to do it easily ?
where can I get my return value ?
I am low at javascript and I just have jquery :-(

My form :

```
<%= form_tag(test_step2_path, method: :get, remote: true, id: 'ttform', 'data-type' => :json) do %>
```

in my javascript :

```
ret = document.getElementById('ttform').submit();
```

and my controller :

```
def step2
respond_to do |format|
  format.html {
    puts ('*************** result1 *************** ')
    return  1
  }
  format.js {
    puts ('*************** result2 *************** ')
    return  1
  }
end
```

end

Ps : also I don't know why, it's the html part in my controller which is called, not the json

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should change method from `:get` to `:post`.
Also pay attention that currently you are not responding with `format.json` but with `format.js`

in the action you can use: `render json: {error: true}` (or any other json),

and the javascript should look something like this:

```
$(document).on("ajax:complete", "#ttform", function(status, response){
    response = JSON.parse(response.responseText); 
    if (response.error) 
        // error behavior 
    else 
        // success behavior 
})
```

Comment: I made the corrections but I still can't get result in  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("form#ttform").on('ajax:success', function(event, data, status, xhr) {
        ...